# Convert.ChangeType throwing Invalid Cast Exception for nullable int

Tags: c#

Getting an Invalid Cast Exception if I call the GetClaimValue method below where T is a nullable int.

```
private static T GetClaimValue<T>(string claimType, IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
{
    var claim = claims.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Type == claimType);

    if (claim != null)
        return (T) Convert.ChangeType(claim.Value, typeof(T));

    return default(T);
}
```

For example:

```
 GetClaimValue<int?>(IdentityServer.CustomClaimTypes.SupplierId, claims)
```

Anyone know of a way to deal with this?

Comment: full exception message please

Comment: what type is claim.Value

Comment: claim.Value will always be a string but could be an empty string

Comment: reading the source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs,3bcca7a9bda4114e seems like you cannot convert to int?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming `Claim.Value` is of type `Object` and you're dynamically converting here, you can't straight up convert an `int` to an `int?` via `Convert.ChangeType`.

One option is to use `Nullable.GetUnderlyingType` which will check if this is a nullable struct case, do the conversion via the underlying data type first, then cast to `T`.

You'll also need to handle the `null` scenario as well.

```
if (claim != null)
{
    var conversionType = typeof(T);

    if (Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(conversionType) != null)
    {
        if (claim.Value == null) //check the null case!
            return default(T);

        //use conversion to `int` instead if `int?`
        conversionType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(conversionType);
    }

    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(claim.Value, conversionType);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I can't explain why it's throwing an exception, however I had a similar situation when I was using `Convert.ChangeType`.

Try grabbing the converter of the type you pass in first, then use that to convert. I've had better results using this method.

```
var converter = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(T));
return (T)converter.ConvertFrom(claim.Value);
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer, and solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Great answer. I had been struggling with `Convert.ChangeType` as well and this solved my issue.